# Writing a php function for advance custom field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I want to implement a progress bar using elementor for WordPress website, for that I've used the widget progress bar, but I'm adding the percentage value dynamically in the progress value, for that I've created a field percentage in my Campaign Details group field in Advance custom field plugin, which have type number and added it to the dynamic tag in progress bar.

After that I've added my php code in snipped code, I'm new to php, so don't know why it is incorrect, I did take the help of chatgpt other sources to find the mistake.

I've wrote two types of function, in the first type, I've used the array to access the campaign details group field to access its fields and in another I've used this notation: *get_field('group_field_name_subfield_name')*

**first type**

```
function calculate_donation_percentage($post_id) {
    $donation_received = get_field('Campaign Details', $post_id)['donation_received'];
    $donation_required = get_field('Campaign Details', $post_id)['donation_required'];

    if ($donation_required == 0) {
        $percentage = 0;
    } else {
        $percentage = ($donation_received / $donation_required) * 100;
    }

    update_field('Campaign Details', array('donation_percentage'=> $percentage), $post_id);
}
add_action('save_post', 'calculate_donation_percentage');
```

**second type**

```
function calculate_donation_percentage($post_id) {
    $donation_received = get_field('Campaign Details_donation_received', $post_id);
    $donation_required = get_field('Campaign Details_donation_required', $post_id);

    if ($donation_required == 0) {
        $percentage = 0;
    } else {
        $percentage = ($donation_received / $donation_required) * 100;
    }

    update_field('Campaign Details_donation_percentage', $percentage, $post_id);
}
add_action('save_post', 'calculate_donation_percentage');
```

I've read that we can add filter method too to add the value into acf field.

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/key=campaign_details_donation_percentage', 'calculate_donation_percentage', 10, 3);
```

Please give me some ideas about how I solve this problem.
[image: it is image of acf fields which i've created]

Answer (score 1):

In first type, I think you typed the wrong field ID 'Campaign Details', IDs does not contain space, check your acf dashboard to find the right field ID, check the attached image.

[image]

Comment: thx for your reply . actually i want to add progress bar , in this i'm adding dynamically adding the the value of percentage using ACF field , therefore i have created a acf field percentage. Now i want to create a php function which returns the percent value , based upon the fields donated amount and required amount, can you please tell me , how to write a working function for that . This percent field also using in every campaign , so for every campaign , i can automatically get the value of percentage value.